# UserInteraction is disabled on animating view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I have button on view, while the view is animating the button is disabled for some reason
Here's the code below , I have allowUserInteraction in options but it doesn't do anything

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 36
    } completion: { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 2, options: .allowUserInteraction) {
            view.frame.origin.y = -100
        } completion: { (_) in
           print("completed")
        }

    }
```

Comment: The animation swallows the touch. You need to put a tap gesture recognizer on the button. Even then, keep in mind that the button is not located where you see it but where it will be at the end of the animation. You'd be a lot happier using a UIViewPropertyAnimator here; it takes care of all this for you.

Comment: I made exact same animation with UIPropertyAnimator but having same problem...
I enabled isUserInteractionEnabled

Comment: I can't explain that without more code. You have not given a complete example that I can try out. But I have created complete examples of this that _you_ can try out, proving that it can be done and showing how.

Comment: I replaced button with tapgesture and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: Notice that that is what I said to do in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

place the button outside of the view you are animating.